# Fastest way to iterate through array multiple times while removing items

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine I have an array of numbers as follows:

`var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`;

This is a simplification, my actual case scenario is much larger(60K or more items).

Basically I need to iterate through the array fully to process a few of the numbers and then keep iterating through the array fully until all of the numbers have been processed (say I can process 1 and 3 on the first iteration and 2, 4 and 5 on the second). **EDIT:** They don't have to be in sequential order.

What I am wondering is - I need to make it so that **items that have already been processed in previous iterations will not be considered again**.

My question is: What is the fastest way to do this, every ms counts because this is being done on a large scale.

I have tried removing the items that have been processed by doing `myArray = myArray.splice(i, 1)` but that is extremely slow. I have also tried setting processed items to `null` and then ignoring `null` items on subsequent iterations. That method seems to work faster but still takes a second or two. Is there some faster method?

Comment: You could sort before processing and then start at a given index moving forward. Or, you could store the last number you processed and do a simple > comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately sorting is not an option for a variety of reasons. The numbers were just an illustration. I am actually processing LAB color values.

Comment: Show us more of the processing. Chances are there are bottlenecks there also

Comment: Have you tried creating a new array with the unprocessed ones, and use the new array for the next iteration?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. It's about as fast as setting previous items to `null` (fast...but takes a few seconds which is still too slow for me)

Comment: How many iterations are you running, generally speaking? How many times do you expect to loop over the full dataset?

Comment: I'm iterating over probably a few thousand times.

Comment: @abagshaw and that's where your performance problem likely lies. Show some code

Comment: This is a much larger problem so I can't really show code - I'm just wondering about optimizations in this specific area. Basically I am trying to organize a list of about 60K LAB colors into fairly distinct groups. On each iteration I take the first color in the remaining colors and then find similar colors to that starting one as I iterate through the full array. I keep repeating until all the colors are gone.

Comment: making a hashmap object would be infinitely faster

Comment: How would a hashmap fit into this problem? I don't really see the application....

Comment: "Iterate 60K LAB colors a few hundred times processing and ignoring a set of values in each iteration" relates more to your problem, the example in question doesn't reflect this.

Comment: "I take the first color in the remaining colors and then find similar colors to that starting one as I iterate through the full array." Is it not possible to create all the groups in one pass?

Comment: Not sure how grouping works but if you can loose group using colors as keys and perhaps array as value during one iteration gives you a start instead of iterating full array for each color instance

Comment: @charlietfl that's actually a really neat idea - thanks! I'll think about it...might be a way to make that work.

Comment: Question is grossly oversimplified for anyone to provide a reasonable answer

Comment: @charlietfl I was just looking for an optimization on a very specified subset of my larger problem - so I didn't think it relevant to elaborate on the whole problem.

Comment: How are you currently handling the new unprocessed data in terms of storage? Are you just pushing the data into one array?

Comment: As oversimplified as your question is, it sounds *similar* to the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm (determining primes and eliminating compound products). It may help to read up on methods/enhancements of that, perhaps it will give you ideas how to better handle your algorithm.

Comment: This is an algorithmic design problem, a kind of clustering problem, and there are quite likely to be solutions which don't involve going through the entire array time after time.

Comment: Use an object, delete processed items?

Comment: If you would provide the algorithm by which you determine whether a color is near the first color you compare with, we could probably help you improve this overall processing. Otherwise putting `null` is probably the fastest method for arrays with a size near 100K.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the index to which you got in the previous processing run. After all, you *don't* want to iterate the array multiple times, you want to iterate it only once but in multiple steps.

```js
function process(arr, step, start) {
    var take = Math.min(arr.length - start, Math.round(1 + Math.random() * 3));
    for (var i = start; i < start + take; i++) {
        console.log("processing item " + arr[i] + " in step " + step);
    }
    return take;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for (var step = 0, i = 0; i < arr.length; step++)
    i += process(arr, step, i);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as I am not necessary processing in sequential order. I suppose I didn't make that clear in my answer. I may first process one item from the beginning and one item from the end - they don't have to be next to each other.

Comment: Yes, you really need to work on your question then and show us what exactly you are currently doing and what you need (e.g. what determines the order for processing). If it's only taking from beginning or end, you could use two indices, but it sounds like something else.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getColorGroup();
    });
    function getColorGroup()
    {
        var colors = ['#FAEBD7', '#00FFFF', '#000000', '#0000FF', '#8A2BE2', '#A52A2A', '#DEB887', '#5F9EA0', '#7FFF00', '#D2691E', '#FF7F50', '#6495ED', '#DC143C', '#00FFFF', '#00008B', '#008B8B', '#B8860B', '#A9A9A9', '#A9A9A9', '#006400', '#BDB76B', '#8B008B', '#556B2F', '#FF8C00', '#9932CC', '#8B0000', '#E9967A', '#8FBC8F', '#483D8B', '#2F4F4F', '#2F4F4F', '#00CED1', '#9400D3', '#FF1493', '#00BFFF', '#696969', '#696969', '#1E90FF', '#B22222', '#228B22', '#FF00FF', '#DCDCDC', '#FFD700', '#DAA520', '#808080', '#808080', '#008000', '#ADFF2F', '#FF69B4', '#CD5C5C', '#4B0082', '#F0E68C', '#E6E6FA', '#7CFC00', '#00FF00', '#32CD32', '#FF00FF', '#800000', '#66CDAA', '#0000CD', '#BA55D3', '#9370DB', '#3CB371', '#7B68EE', '#00FA9A', '#48D1CC', '#C71585', '#191970', '#FFE4E1', '#FFE4B5', '#FFDEAD', '#000080', '#808000', '#6B8E23', '#FFA500', '#FF4500', '#DA70D6', '#EEE8AA', '#98FB98', '#AFEEEE', '#DB7093', '#FFDAB9', '#CD853F', '#FFC0CB', '#DDA0DD', '#B0E0E6', '#800080', '#663399', '#FF0000', '#BC8F8F', '#4169E1', '#8B4513', '#FA8072', '#F4A460', '#2E8B57', '#A0522D', '#C0C0C0', '#87CEEB', '#6A5ACD', '#708090', '#708090', '#00FF7F', '#4682B4', '#D2B48C', '#008080', '#D8BFD8', '#FF6347', '#40E0D0', '#EE82EE', '#F5DEB3', '#FFFF00', '#9ACD32'];
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % colors.length);
        var color = colors[randomIndex];
        console.log(color);
        var tasks = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i += 10)
        {
            tasks.push(findColor(color, colors, i, 10));
        }
        var group = [];
        $.when.apply($, tasks).done(function () {
            for(var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++)
            {
                group = group.concat(arguments[j]);
            }
            console.log(group);
        });
    }

    function findColor(sample, colors, startIndex, segmentSize)
    {
        return $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                var result = [];
                var pattern = /#([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})/i;
                var sampleMatch = pattern.exec(sample);
                if (sampleMatch) {
                    for (var i = startIndex; i < startIndex + segmentSize && i < colors.length; i++) {
                        var match = pattern.exec(colors[i]);
                        if (match) {
                            if (sampleMatch[1].toUpperCase() == match[1].toUpperCase()
                                ||
                                sampleMatch[2].toUpperCase() == match[2].toUpperCase()
                                ||
                                sampleMatch[3].toUpperCase() == match[3].toUpperCase()) {
                                result.push(colors[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, 0);
        }).promise();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with the question?

Comment: Why are you using deferreds when there is nothing asynchronous?

Comment: @Bergi, your're right. I tempted to show a demo with multiple asynchronous operations on partitions of a color set but I didn't make those operations async at all. Thanks!